# JOOQ materialized views

Tags: java, sql, jooq

is it possible to create materialized views using the JOOQ builder? Something like this

```
DSL.createMaterializedView().execute()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jOOQ 3.14, not yet: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9483

But you can use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) to work around this limitation, to at least get *some* type safety in your statement:

```java
ctx.execute("create materialized view view_name as {0}", select);
```